# @AfterReturning for multiple methods in a same controller AOP

Tags: aop, aspectj, aspect, pointcut

I want to call multiple methods included in a same controller. But methods are different from input parameters. So I need to use one aspect method for those three methods included in same controller.

```
 @AfterReturning("execution(* com.intervest.medical.aggregator.controller.CommonController.*(..)) && args(request,registerParam,..)")
```

Above line of code is oky for one method. because that method's arguements are request and registerParam. but other two methods don't include these parameters. Those methods have parameters different from this. So How do I change these line of code which suit for all the three methods.

```
 public RegisterResult doScreenXXX(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam) {}
 
 public XMLOutput getXXX(@RequestBody String hash) throws Exception {}
  
 public XMLOutput reScreenAndGetXXXX(@RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam) {}
```

I have mentioned those three methods in below.

I have used joinPoint.getArgs()[] also. but didn't get any positive response. Is this correct?

```
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.intervest.medical.aggregator.controller.CommonController.*(..)) && args(request,registerParam,..)")
    public void doScreenAspect(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam){}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.intervest.medical.aggregator.controller.CommonController.*(..)) && args(registerParam,..)")
    public void rescreeningAspect(@RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam){}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.intervest.medical.aggregator.controller.CommonController.*(..)) && args(hash,..)")
    public void getXMLAspect(@RequestBody String hash){}


    @AfterReturning("doScreenAspect(request,registerParam) || rescreeningAspect(registerParam) || getXMLAspect(hash)")
    public void aspect(JoinPoint joinPoint, @RequestBody RegisterParam registerParam, HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String hash) {
        System.out.println("TRTRTRTRTRTRTRTRTRTT");
        System.out.println(joinPoint.getArgs());
      }
```

Hope your help for clarify this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Do share all the method signatures that needs to be adviced .

Comment: I added method signatures @R.G

Comment: using `args()` limits matching the method executions for the arguments given. Looking at the method arguments and different types for the params , you could leverage `JoinPoint.getArgs()` https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()

Comment: Can you please explain further? @R.G

Comment: Please go through : [Passing Parameters to Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing) , especially *The args(account,..) part of the pointcut expression* . Also [Access to the Current JoinPoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing). All these are under assumption that you are using spring AOP and not pure AspectJ

Comment: One suggestion is to add a custom annotation to these methods and use it in the pointcut `@annotation`

Comment: Hi all, Again I edited my code. I changed it by using @Pointcut. But still it doesn't work. Can you please check this?

Comment: @ddmmcc single advice method for all the three controller methods with different argument sequence and argument types will not be possible with `args()` Pointcut Designator. Either you may go with three different `@AfterReturning`  advice methods or with single `@AfterReturning` method without `args()` , then use `joinPoint.getArgs()` and reflection to identify the argument type etc for processing. Simplest would be to use three different `@AfterReturning` advice methods if there are no specific requirements to use single method.

Comment: I took the liberty of closing the question as a duplicate, because what R.G correctly explained so well is also captured in my answer to that other question.

Comment: If you search the site here for ["ambiguous parameter binding"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1082681+ambiguous+parameter+binding), you also find several related questions and my answers to them, also showing sample code how to factor out common code from multiple advice methods into one helper method, as suggested by R.G.

Comment: Yes @kriegaex. I solved this issue as suggested by R.G